# How to dismiss buttons with models works in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to know that, why dismiss button does not work when I'm using it with model. Please visit the below link and suggest me how it is possible ?

http://builderfunding.co.in/doylesweb/index.html

Here is the code -
`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">My Booking</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal1">How it Works?</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Please post what you have tried already first, so we can tell you what went wrong and suggest edits from your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi its because your css code model and modal-backdrop   both codes having almost same z-index values

```
.modal {      
z-index: 1050;    
} 

.modal-backdrop{
   z-index:1040;
 }
```

remove  modal-backdrop z-index , it will work fine (Bootstrap.min.css) 
[ http://builderfunding.co.in/doylesweb/index.html ]